# Restrict File Access From URL

Tags: asp.net, redirect, hosting, web-hosting, directory-listing

I have a site developed in ASP.NET which is hosted.Now in my site there is folder known as "upload" in which some .rar files are saved for private use.When I directly type the url, the file gets downloaded.
Say suppose the file is at "http://www.mathew.com/uploads/mine.rar",if i type the url in the browser and hit enter,it downloads the file even though directory listing is not there.

I want to restrict this..How can I achieve it.
Thanks,
Mathew

Comment: Are you using membership and role providers?

Comment: no i am not using such things..its a simple site.

Comment: `Authorization` can be used in any asp.net site. You don't have to use membership or roles provider for that.

Answer (score 6):

You can restrict that by authorization. Put a `web.config` file in this folder with:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT :**

This won't work since rar files are not handled by asp.net, so in addition you need to add a handler for asp.net treat rar files like aspx files:

For classic mode:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.rar" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

For integrated mode (default for `iis 7.5` and `VS 2012`)

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="rar" path="*.rar" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You're right. rar files are not handled by default by asp.net. Edited my answer to fix that.